# Serialize XML without including parent element

Tags: c#, xml

Ok so I'm not sure this is aptly titled, but here's what I'm trying to do. I have a class structure like this:

```
public class Container
{
    public List<Violation> Violations {get;set;}
}
```

When serialized to XML, this would look like:

```
<Container>
  <Violations>
    <Violation>..</Violation>
    <Violation>..</Violation>
  </Violations>
</Container>
```

What I need it to look like when it gets serialized is this:

```
<Container>
  <Violation>..</Violation>
  <Violation>..</Violation>
</Container>
```

Is there a way to define this behavior with XML attributes on the class definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `XmlElementAttribute`:

```
[XmlElement("Violation")]
public List<Violation> Violations {get;set;}
```